# Remove the 1st line of a file in Java regardless of newline type without calling exec or iterating over it line by line

Tags: java, io, newline

I'm trying to write a method in Java that removes the first line of a file.

First idea (rejected because calling .exec is not a good practice)

```
public void removeHeader(String fileName) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(fileName)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("fileName was empty");
    }

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sed -i 1d " + fileName);

    if (p.waitFor() != 0) {
        throw new IOException("Failed to remove the header from " + fileName);
    }
}
```

Second idea (rejected in CR because iterating over every line and writing it into a new file is slow and not stylish).

```
public void removeHeader(String fileName) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(fileName)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("fileName was empty");
    }

    File inFile = new File(fileName);
    File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

    BufferedReader br = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

        String line = null;
        boolean first = true;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!first) {
                pw.println(line);
                pw.flush();
            }

            first = false;
        } 
    }
    finally {
        pw.close();
        br.close();
    }

    if (inFile.exists() && tempFile.exists()) {
        inFile.delete();
        tempFile.renameTo(inFile);
    }
}
```

I want my solution to work regardless of newline format and be easy to read. Is there a solution that meets all these needs?

Comment: My response would be to KISS: Keep It Simple, Silly! Unless this really is a mission-critical part of your application, do it either way and move on to the next thing. Thinking that everything needs to be as optimized as it can be can cause problems in terms of delays in getting a larger project done

Comment: @KenWhite that should be an answer.

Comment: I very much agree, but the person doing my CR has a very different opinion.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not a Java person, but there's no way (Java or otherwise) to remove content from the beginning of a file without rewriting the remaining content (unless you can access the underlying file system to move the starting block of the file, which would defeat your "easy to read" requirement).

I sense premature optimization here, unless the files are really large.

Answer (score 2):

You have to read and copy anything you want to keep (Even `sed` is doing that).

The second version can be improved slightly by simply skipping the first line by a separate read before the loop and then you won't have to check whether you're on the first line every time through the loop.

The second could also gain a bit of elegance by writing a [FilterReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterReader.html) that skips the first line.  It's not likely worth the trouble for this purpose, but learning to implement such a filter is worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be shortened like this (requires Java7):

- Open a `FileInputStream`
- Read it to the first line break
- Copy the rest of it with [Files.copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29)

But otherwise, as other said, there's no easy way to cut out the first part of a file.